# When a question is closed as a duplicate, could we add a link to the original question?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, closed-questions, hyperlinks

In situations where a [question has been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747973/does-this-have-any-advantage) in relation to another post, could there be a simple addition of a link to the related post?

> closed as exact duplicate by **Daniel Pryden, Cody Gray, Martin, Alin Purcaru, finnw** Apr 22 at 15:21

becomes..

> closed as exact duplicate of **[this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116312/could-we-add-a-link-to-moderated-posts)** by **Daniel Pryden, Cody Gray, Martin, Alin Purcaru, finnw** Apr 22 at 15:21

Comment: Perhaps it should be reopened, since the "master" was deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system has changed a bit over the years. Nowadays, Community doesn't edit the question anymore, instead, the link to the original question is shown as another banner at the top of the page:

[image]

([live example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123519/295232))

Answer (score 7):

The link is edited into the top of the post by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

[image: Screenshot of the top of the closed post]

Comment: ...which, [in this specific case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132777/do-you-prefix-your-instance-variable-with-this-in-java), is a dead end. Maybe that explains why the OP was confused/asking?

Comment: @Arjan - The "master" post in that case was later deleted

Comment: Sure, @Nick, we know that's a different problem. I just wondered if seeing that 404 might be why the OP was asking for a link: *maybe* the OP did click it, but did not realize that was actually the link that was asked for? (My previous comment was a bit confusing indeed.)

Comment: @Arjan Ah, maybe; I didn't actually click it