# When exactly does the Unsung Hero badge get awarded?

Tags: support, badges

A while ago, I spotted the gold badge, [Unsung Hero](https://serverfault.com/badges/84/unsung-hero), which carries the description, `Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total`.

The way I interpret that is that you need more than 10 zero score accepted answers, and at least 25% of your accepted answers need to be zero score.

I'm guessing my interpretation is incorrect, as looking at my own profile, I have:

- 35 accepted answers with scores
- 12 accepted answers without scores
- 47 total accepted answers
- 12 out of 47 is 25.53% zero score answers

So by my reckoning, I should have that badge.

My zero score accepted answer percentage was higher a week or so ago (I seem to recall it was around 27% or 28%), but has since decreased as I've had some answers accepted recently that had been up voted.

Can anyone explain this? I'm guessing I'm misinterpreting the badge description?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/121674/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You get the badge when you have more than 10 accepted answers, whose score is zero; those answers are at least 25% of [all your accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement/57245#57245). For example, if you have only 4 accepted answers (with a score of zero) out of 40 accepted answers, you don't get the badge.

Note that an answer with a score of zero is any answer that has a [net up vote / down vote count of zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97937/do-negative-score-accepted-answers-count-towards-tenacious-unsung-hero/97940#97940).

Other restrictions that apply to the answers for which you can gain the badge are:

- Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included
- The accepted answers need to be at least ten days old

Comment: The description states zero score, rather than no up-votes, so I'd take that literally as meaning 'zero score' answers, but I agree it could easily be misunderstood

Comment: _Score_ in the Stack Exchange case means the difference between the number of up-votes, and the number of down-votes, which is also 0 when the answer has never been voted before the badge is assigned.

Comment: The description `Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total` is a little misleading in my opinion if it means 25% of _all_ answers.

Comment: @Bryan Both figures do indeed refer to *accepted* answers only.

Comment: For info, just counted up, and 6 of my 12 zero score answers were answers to my own questions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Have these restrictions changed?   Out of my accepted answers more than 10 days old I have 13 TOTAL, and 8 ZERO SCORE which is almost 75% according to your post.  Any idea why I have not gotten the badge?

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Because 8 is not more then 10

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Both the conditions must be true. If that is valid for 8 answers out of 9, for example, you don't get the badge, in the same way you don't get it for 10 answers out of 100.

Comment: I noticed the query page has a 2 days delay. I should have the badge but the query doesn't say it yet because of the delay. Does the badge rely on the live data or on the data available from the query page ?

Comment: the OP's analysis was right granting that he only counted non-self accepted answers and his "zero-score" answer meant "net-zero" so i assume the only reason he didnt get the badge was due to the latest accepted not being 10 days old. did i understand it correctly?

Answer (score 10):

I originally searched on ServerFault meta, which didn't return any results, but never thought to search on StackOverflow meta until my question was migrated here.

But now that I have searched here on SO, I think I've worked it out, from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86376/154539).

A few of those zero score answers, were answers I'd posted to my own questions, which for obvious reasons, don't count.