# Tenacious badge not awarded to me

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I answered 39 questions out of which 9 are zero score accepted answers.

Why did I am not awarded the Tenacious badge?

Comment: You have 9 zero accepted answers.

Comment: Tenacious badge is awarded for more than 5 and **20% of total** of accepted answer

Comment: @Vigbyor I count eight.

Comment: @CRUSADER: 9 out of 39 is 23% of the total... Your point?

Comment: I can't see the attraction of this baggage.

Comment: @michaelb958 , http://stackoverflow.com/users/1758368/rj1990?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=1 4 on first page and 5 on second page.

Comment: @Vigbyor There are only four on the second page.

Comment: @RJ1990 Uh oh, you're down to seven. No, six. Wait, make that five. Actually, four.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your zero-score accepted answers are all [at least 10 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123519/when-exactly-does-the-unsung-hero-badge-get-awarded) and still at 0 votes, then the total count of accepted answers is taken into account.

Not all of those 0-score answers are old enough; I count 5 that are 10 days old or more, and with 39 accepted answers you need 8. In a few days time, if all those 0-score answers are still at 0, and you didn't add *more* accepted answers to your total, you'll be awarded the badge.

Comment: After 10 Days, If I answers any Question and Ratio got Disturbed then? I think in this way I am not eligible for that.

Comment: @RJ1990: indeed; or people see your question here and start voting on those answers..