# Why is there some data unaccessible from the Data Explorer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, data-explorer

I was wondering why I didn't get the *Unsung Hero* badge when I theoretically should have it on Stack Overflow.

The [How Unsung am I?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/7521/7521/how-unsung-am-i) requests shows only 10 unscored answers, the real count is 11 but there's an answer not showing in the Data Explorer.

Indeed, the answer of this question: [Angular 6 and typed API data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480397/angular-6-and-typed-api-data/52480596#52480596) doesn't show at all: [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/903190)

I noticed there was a 2-day delay, but this delay has passed already.

Comment: No it’s not a two day delay. The data’s only updated on Sunday

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/282094)    https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123522/282094 - 10 days after it's accepted. Also, follow the links in the first one's banner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That post is from September 24th.

If you check SEDE's homepage, you'll notice a message on the right saying

> Data updated Sep 23 at 8:04

It's an excellent source of data but it's not able to predict the future. Your post will be there the next time it refreshes, which happens every week on Sunday morning UTC.

Comment: Oh okay, yesterday I read "data updated two days ago" then I thought it was updated every day based on 2-day old data.

Comment: Will accept as soon as I'm able to

Comment: By the way, the badges rely on the same data source as the data explorer?

Comment: Not really; e.g. you can't predict the Electorate badge because votes are anonymous. For Unsung Hero, it should work.

Comment: Okay but I mean, it does not rely on live data?

Comment: The badge awarding system relies on live data. Otherwise, all badges would be awarded on Sunday, and they aren't :)